# Style text nested inside a SVG

Tags: html, css, spotfire

I have the following HTML, dynamicaly generated by TIBCO Spotfire.

```css
div#mod-container text {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  color: #000058;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div id="mod-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 100">
    <g id="backgroundLayer">
      <text class="displayText" x="180" y="50" alignment-baseline="central">
        15918
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I would like to change some of the style parameters from the  inside the SVG, and I have did the following:

```css
div#mod-container text {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  color: #000058;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

and

```css
text.displayText {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  color: #000058;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Unfortunately, none of the above approaches have worked. Any idea would be welcome.

Marcio

Answer (score 1):

Only a limited css style rules are applicable in `<svg>` elements and its sub-elements.

In your case, replace color, with fill. rest all properties should be working. And yes, both the ways you have used to style the element is correct. Better is to use the css class to style, rather than the ID.

```
text.displayText {
    font-family: "Segoe UI" !important;
    fill: #000058 !important; // changed from color to fill
    font-size: 22px !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

Check https://css-tricks.com/svg-properties-and-css/ for detailed information of which CSS properties are supported in SVG elements and its sub-elements.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```css
div#mod-container .displayText {
  font-family: "Belanosima"; /* works; just replaced with a random font that is on Google.Fonts for the snippet */
  fill: #000058; /* changed color -> fill */
  font-size: 22px; /* works */
  font-weight: 700; /* works, just replaced 500 with 700 */
  /* font: 700 22px "Belanosima"; <- alternative */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Belanosima:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="mod-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 100">
    <g id="backgroundLayer">
      <text class="displayText" x="180" y="50" alignment-baseline="central">
        15918
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by **Sudipto Roy** and **dragomirik**
SVG `<text>` elements are colored via `fill` attribute/property.

You can also apply the `currentColor` keyword value to inherit colors from parent `color` properties:

#### Example1: add `currentColor`

```css
.displayText {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  fill:currentColor;
  color: red;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div id="mod-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 100">
    <g id="backgroundLayer">
      <text class="displayText" x="180" y="50" alignment-baseline="central">
        15918
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

#### Example2: inherit from parent HTML element

```css
.color-red{
  color: red
}


.color-green{
  color: green
}



.displayText {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  fill:currentColor;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-red">
  <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought.</p>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 100">
      <text class="displayText" x="180" y="50" alignment-baseline="central">
        15918
      </text>
  </svg>
</div>


<div class="color-green">
  <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought.</p>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 100">
      <text class="displayText" x="180" y="50" alignment-baseline="central">
        15918
      </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

See also ["Css-tricks: Cascading SVG Fill Color"](https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `transform: scale(0.0878);` for the size and `fill="currentColor"` then use regular css for color.

Why?  The pixel of the svg is 360. 16px (default font for most browsers)
SO we take that 16 and divided by 360 is 0.044444 so we can use that 0.044em for the plain text.

Now how to scale the font in the svg with a transform? We scale to that amount which is the same 10px.  I included a font of `10px` and one of  `font-size: 0.04444em;` from the body font size of `360px`so you can see all three visually.

- 100px font in a 360px size thus
- 100/16 is 6.25 - so 6.25 times 16px size.
- 360 / 16 is 22.5 (divided by 100 for the 100px)
- SO 0.00225 * 6.25 is 0.0878 so we scale by that.

I added some JavaScript just to show the computed sizes and some regular text to associate those with.

I also included a

```js
let calcSize = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#mod-container svg text.displayText')).fontSize;
let bodySize = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body')).fontSize;
let plainSize = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.test-plain-text')).fontSize;
let plainSizeBase = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.test-plain-textbase')).fontSize;
let modSize = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#mod-container')).fontSize;
let modTSize = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#backgroundLayer>text.displayText')).fontSize;
console.log(calcSize, bodySize,"Plain:",plainSize,"Base:", plainSizeBase,"mod:",modSize,"ModText:",modTSize);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 360px;
}

#mod-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#mod-container svg #backgroundLayer text.displayText{
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  color: #000058;
  font-weight: 800;
  transform: scale(0.0878);
}

.test-plain-text {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  color: #000058;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 0.04444444444em;
}

.test-plain-textbase {
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  color: #000058;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-plain-text">15918  16/360 = 0.04444em size this is 16px font plain</div>
<div class="test-plain-textbase">15918 this is 10px base</div>
<div id="mod-container">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 100">
    <g id="backgroundLayer">
    <text class="displayText" x="180" y="50" alignment-baseline="central" style="font-size: 100px;" fill="currentColor">15918 </text>
    </g>
    </svg>
</div>100/16 is 6.25 - so 6.25 times 16 size.
360 / 16 is 22.5
SO 0.00225 % of 6.25 is 0.0878 so we scale by that
```